# Create anonymous class extending inner abstract class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have the following scenario - a class which contains an inner abstract class:

```
class A {

   private int Afield;
   public void Amethod() { ... }

   protected abstract class InnerOfA {
       ...
       protected abstract void doSomething();
   }
}
```

Now inside a method of a different class I want to create an *anonymous class* extending the `InnerOfA`:

```
class B {
   public void Bmethod(A instanceOfA)
   {
       A.InnerOfA instance = instanceOfA.new InnerOfA()
       {
           @Override
           protected void doSomething()
           {
                // Here I want to use the private fields and methods of A.
           }
       }
   }
}
```

But for some reason (which I don't understand) I cannot use the `Afield` and `Amethod` inside the override of `doSomething`. Why is this happening? The anonymous instance should still internally belong to the `instanceOfA` and hence should be able to access it's internals.

Comment: Reread the definition of `private`. `B` (and its anonymous inner classes) are not supposed to be able to access `private` members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private fields/methods **can only be** accessed within the class they are **declared** (subclassing is not enough to access `private`).

Answer (score 1):

if you define

```
public void Bmethod(final A instanceOfA)
```

you can call

```
@Override
protected void doSomething()
{
    instanceOfA.Amethod();
}
```

but you cannot access `Afield` because it is private